# How to calculate MD5 Hash when creating Zip with 7zip

Tags: hash, md5, 7zip

I am building an application that will use 7zip to create ZIPs. I know that 7zip will report the CRC's for the files within the ZIP but I would like to calculate the MD5 hash values of the files within the zip as well. Does anyone know if 7zip is capable of doing this or will I have to use a different utility (like md5sum) to calculate the hashes prior to zipping them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Zip algorithm uses CRC checksums to verify the archive is not corrupt. It does not have a concept of md5 checksums.

You will need to calculate all the hashes before creating your archive.